# Convert mp4 video to avi video using imageio package

Tags: python, ffmpeg, deep-learning

I use the python `imageio` package to convert a `.mp4` video to a `.avi` video, keeping the fps and size same. The following is my code:

```
import imageio

src_dir = "my/source/video.mp4"
dst_dir = "my/dst/video.avi"

reader = imageio.get_reader(src_dir)
fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']
writer = imageio.get_writer(dst_dir, fps=fps)

for im in reader:
    writer.append_data(im[:, :, :])
writer.close()
```

I successfully make it. 
However, I find that the `video.mp4` is 27.1 MB, while the `video.avi` is only 3.70 MB.
Then I use `cv2` to do the same thing:

```
import cv2

src_dir = "my/source/video.mp4"
dst_dir = "my/dst/video_1.avi"

video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src_dir)
fps = video_cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
size = (int(video_cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),   
        int(video_cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))  
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(dst_dir, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, size) 

success, frame = video_cap.read()
while success:
    video_writer.write(frame)
    success, frame = video_cap.read()
```

This time I get a `video_1.avi`, which is 65.6 MB.
My questions:

1. What is the different between these two method, why the `video.avi` (using `imageio` method) is so small;
2. Is there any problem to use the `video.avi` (using `imageio` method) to train a 3D-CNN instead of using `video_1.avi` (using `cv2` method)?

---

*supplement*
Here is the information of my video file:

```
lichenyang@lichenyang-All-Series:~/chalearn2014/script$ file video.mp4
video.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
lichenyang@lichenyang-All-Series:~/chalearn2014/script$ file video.avi
video.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 20.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264
lichenyang@lichenyang-All-Series:~/chalearn2014/script$ file video_1.avi
video_1.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 20.00 fps, video: Motion JPEG
```

Answer (score 0):

I test both methods, and found that all sounds are missing by both methods.

1. I find the difference by file command:

   sam@sam:~/code/python$ file video.avi

   video.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 480 x 368, 25.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264

   sam@sam:~/code/python$ file video_1.avi

   video_1.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 480 x 360, 25.00 fps, video: Motion JPEG

   sam@sam:~/code/python$
2. I think all avi videos are good enough. I didn't see any problem. You can try for it and share more information to us.

By the way, I need to change the second one code, due to Opencv3.2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import cv2

src_dir = "1.mp4"
dst_dir = "2.avi"

video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src_dir)
#fps = video_cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
#cv2.cv會出現錯誤：AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
#在Opencv3.2中cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS需要改為cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS
#也就是都要去掉CV_字眼
fps = video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
size = (int(video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),   
        int(video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))  
#video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(dst_dir, cv2.FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, size) 
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(dst_dir, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, size) 

success, frame = video_cap.read()
while success:
    video_writer.write(frame)
    success, frame = video_cap.read()
```

Comment: As you did, I see the information of my video files, I show it as a supplement
above. Maybe the file size difference between two `.avi` file is caused by encoding method difference (`video: H.264 X.264 or H.264`and`video: Motion JPEG`). In addition, the resolution of the three videos (`video.mp4`, `video.avi`, `video_1.avi`) is the same (640*480). I don't know why the resolution of your two `.avi` videos are different.